# Measure the use of CPU of a Nodejs process from within the same Nodejs process

Tags: node.js

I would like to measure the CPU consumed by a main nodejs process, i.e. a single process which does not have any child process, from within that same process.

From the documentation it seems that `process.cpuUsage` is the guy I am looking for. There is something though that I do not fully grasp.

From the official documentation

> The process.cpuUsage() method returns the user and system CPU time
>   usage of the current process, in an object with properties user and
>   system, whose values are microsecond values (millionth of a second).
>   These values measure time spent in user and system code respectively,
>   and **may end up being greater than actual elapsed time if multiple CPU
>   cores are performing work for this process**.

What I do not understand is the last sentence. If a node process is single threaded how can it be that **multiple CPU cores perform work for this process**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I do not understand is the last sentence. If a node process is single threaded how can it be that multiple CPU cores perform work for this process?

Nodejs runs your Javascript as a single thread (unless you specifically use Worker Threads), but the node.js library itself uses a number of native threads.  For example, the file I/O part of libuv uses a thread pool for disk I/O and multiple threads can be involved in running the native code part of the `fs` module.  In addition, some add-on modules that have native code may use their own native code threads to help them accomplish their goal.

So, in a running node.js program, there may be multiple CPUs contributing to the overall code of the process depending upon exactly what it's doing.